# Ubuntu PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in.. when calling PHP script

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

I run [Ubuntu desktop 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) LTS (Trusty Tahr), and I am trying to setup Apache 2, MySQL server and PHP, but I keep gettin the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in..

What I have done is these changes in the correct php.ini:

uncomment:

> extension=msqli.so

set path aquired from phpinfo():

> extension_dir = "./usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs"

Why is the mysqli function to connect to the database still undefined?

Comment: I suspect you don't have `php_mysql` package installed.  Run this on the command line: `dpkg --get-selections |grep php5-mysql` and see whether it reports `install` as the status.

Comment: I'm not sure how the Debian packages differ in names vs CentOS, but do you have `php-mysql` or `php-mysqlnd` installed? The latter would be preferred

Comment: `msqli.so` is not a valid extension filename. it should be `mysqli.so`

Comment: sudo apt-get install php5-mysql  --- will install it and after you need add extension=mysqli.so in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: Thanks @Tasos. Working here as well.

Answer (score 8):

running updates is usually recommended

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then install needed version

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case php5-mysql was missing from my Ubuntu server. After installing the package it is working fine with mysqli adapter.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

It resolved my CodeIgniter 3.0 mysqli connection valid.

Comment: don't forget to restart apache after that `sudo service apache2 restart`